# How does traffic flow from Azure virtual machine to data dog

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, datadog

I have installed data dog agent on one of my virtual machines When I have altered my NSG so that all "Outbound-connections" are denied, I am still able to see "CPU metric" getting updated on Data dog dashboard. I would like to know where this information is going from Azure to Datadog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datadog, like OMS and other monitoring software uses the Azure VM agent to steam the information. Once this agent is installed on the system we are able to gather the info needed.

The VM agent is not something that goes out over the internet like other connections. Hence, you should still see the reporting available. Rather, it should be a direct connection from the Hyper-V manager and the VM itself. This therefore, bypassing any NSG rules you would have in place.

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed data dog agent on one of my virtual machines

Datadog agent will collect system metrics and **forward** to Datadog.

Datadog agent works like this:

[image]

Also you can try to perform a network capture on your Azure VM, then we are able to find the detailed of the agent behavior.

Here is the network capture in my test VM:

[image]

We can find that **Datadog agent forward over HTTPS(443) to Datadog HQ**.

After you deny port 443 in NSG outbound rules, the datadog will not get your metrics:

[image]

More information about datadog agent, please refer to this official [article](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/203034929-What-is-the-Datadog-Agent-What-resources-does-it-consume-).